# checking the password in php?

Tags: php, passwords, forms

how can i check if the password is more than 6 letters using php, this is for my registration form. :)) thanks

Comment: It might be a good idea to check it with javascript before it's passed over to the server as well. Save a call, and save the user some frustration. W/ jQuery: $('#passwordInput').value().length

Comment: thanks im already using jquery, but doing through ajax. :)) thanks @alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if(strlen(trim($password)) > 6){
  // do something here
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I'd do the `trim()`. It might be useful if people are likely to paste passwords rather than typing them, but it might prevent enterprising users from putting a space on the end of their password.

Comment: thanksm can i just ask you how do you check for unwanted characters in the username, i only want letters, numbers, and underscores, and no spaces obviously

Comment: Was on my way out, saw your comment and did a quick search, this should help `if((ereg("^[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+$", $your_variable_here)) { // value username }`

Comment: @staticsan .. i think you have a very valid point, my main reason of using it was to disallow people from just entering 6 spaces in there. something to think about for getaway :)

Comment: Lazy users are more likely to type `123456` or `password` as a bad password rather than six spaces. If you want to prevent bad passwords, you should do it properly: check for all the things that make a password "strong", assign points for each check and then require a minimum point score corresponding to most checks passing.

Answer (score 1):

I think you will find this very usefull:

http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Validating-User-Input.html

Good luck, Please tell me if you need any help with it!

Comment: I would definitely go with Sabeen´s answer, if you want to read further, read my answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the strlen() function.